# Dragging a link to the browser with jQuery drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I have a small script where you can drag the link, but I also want it to be dropable on the browser bar so that you can easily bookmark a page or share it etc. How can I make this possible?

Here is an example of one of the drag functions I use now:
http://jsfiddle.net/NzbPW/2/

Thanks in advance.

[Edit:]
I found an example of what I kind of want, try to drag the '+bitmark' button:
http://bitly.com/a/tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's only possible with the native browser functionality (see for example http://jsfiddle.net/NzbPW/3/ ) and not with a custom drag and drop script. Still, there is one way to do this, and that would be using the drag and drop native functionality as defined in HTML5 (see for example this: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_draganddrop.asp ).

Comment: I updated my question, Bitly has a function like that too. And I use dragging functions in the page itself so static is not an option, sadly.

Comment: I just noticed that Bitly, which I used as an example, alsof uses HTML5. I'll give that a try then, thanks!